# Ferramentas para protótipo App mobile

Tags: android, mobile, layout, react-native

O que vocês costumam utilizar para fazer o protótipo de um aplicativo mobile, antes do seu desenvolvimento? Papel mesmo, alguma ferramenta pra desenhar quais seriam as screens e suas navegações, etc.

Comment: Eu não sou o tipo de pessoa que consegue realizar protótipos, pois eles costumam ficar mais encaixados na minha cabeça, mas as que conheço são: https://marvelapp.com/ e Sketch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As que conheço são:

- [Adobe XD (Experience Design)](http://www.adobe.com/br/products/experience-design.html)
- [Marvel Apps](https://marvelapp.com)
- [Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com)

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo utilizar bastante o Pencil (https://pencil.evolus.vn).

Ela é personalizável nos elementos, open source e multi-plataforma(O que pra mim é muito importante)

Não espere um conjunto muito grande de componentes. Apesar de ser personalizável, não existem muitos elementos prontos por ai.

Apesar de ter alguns bugs e pouca variedade de elementos, ainda acho uma boa ferramenta de prototipagem.